Quotient spaces of a rectangle and homeomorphism
If we have a rectangle with vertices labelled cyclically as $1,2,3,4$, and if we identify the directed edge $(1,2)$ with the directed edge $(4,3)$, then the space we get is homeomorphic to a cylinder.
Now, in $3$D-space, we twist the directed edge $(1,2)$ twice by $180^0$ (around its center) and then attach it to the directed edge $(4,3)$; one would say that this space is still homeomorphic to cylinder.
But, I could not understand whether we can pass from the second cylinder to the first without cutting it? If not, how do we justify it?

Homeomorphism is not bound to any "ambient space" such as 3D space. The notion you are probably thinking of (transforming a shape into another in 3D space without cutting) is isotopy. See also this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383751/how-is-a-doubly-twisted-cylinder-different-from-a-cylinder

I recommend taking a thick rubber band (or anything shaped like a transmission belt), holding it between your hands and then twisting the part held by your right hand by 180 degrees.
